# Starting a service using an alarm manager not working

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to start a service (NotificationService.java) using an alarm manager in my main activity (Home.java). I put a log after executing AlarmManager's setInexactRepeating, and it shows success executing setInexactRepeating, but the service is never started.

Here is the code to start the service:

```
 public void startService(Context context){
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, NotificationService.class);
    int minutes = 1 ;
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(Home.this, 0, i, 0);
    am.cancel(pi);

        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
           System.currentTimeMillis(),
            minutes*60*1000, pi);   
        Log.e("Service Started","Halilujia");
}
```

Here is the declaration in the manifest:

```
     <service
      android:name=".services.NotificationService"
      android:enabled="true">

 </service>

public class NotificationService extends Service {

private WakeLock mWakeLock;
private Context activity = getApplicationContext();
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // obtain the wake lock
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DebuggingTag");
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    // check the global background data setting
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (!cm.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
        stopSelf();
        return;
    }
    Log.e("Just before request","Just before Request");
            // send http request here and create notification

}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
Log.e("Onstart Called","Onstart has been Called");
handleIntent(intent);
}


@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.e("Onstart Called","Onstart has been Called");
handleIntent(intent);
return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }

 public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
mWakeLock.release();
 }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` to be `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`

Comment: Didn't work. Do you think its the alarm manager or could it be the service itself?

Comment: Are you seeing the Log message from your `onStartCommand(...)` method?

Comment: No, only the log after AlarmManager's setInexactRepeating

Comment: OK so it looks like the alarm is the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is a new (edited) answer...

Your manifest declaration for the `Service` is...

```
<service
    android:name=".services.NotificationService"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

...which is declaring `NotificationService` as being contained in a package called `services`. Example...

Main package is `com.example.MyApp` and the service is in `com.example.MyApp.services`.

Placing the code file for the service in `/src/services` doesn't change the package name / path used by the `android:name` attribute.

To resolve the issue either change the declaration to use `android:name=".NotificationService` or create a separate `com.example.MyApp.services` package and place the service code file in there.

Comment: I tried it, but nothing new happened. Could it be the manifest declaration somehow. I put the NotificationService.java inside src/services/     where I created the folder services.

Comment: @Pacemaker : So `src/services/` is just a folder and not a package? If that's the case then yes, the manifest declaration is wrong. Change the name attribute to `android:name=".NotificationService"`if the service is in your main package. If you want to separate the service from the other code files then use a new package rather than a new /src folder, e.g., com.mycompany.myapp.services. You'd then be able to use `android:name=".services.NotificationService"`

Comment: Thanks, changing into the packages worked. Post this as an answer so I can accept it.